# What's the best practice to using the static variable in C# of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

According to this [tutorial demonstrated on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOmBhbVz5yQ&feature=youtu.be&t=429)

It is working to make a static variable to hold the score and change it in other scripts when the player should be awarded, but it also advised that using static variable in C# script of Unity might not be recommended.

Flowing is what I do to construct the scoring system:

in `ScoreManger` which was bonded to an UI Text component to show the score:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int score;
    Text text;
    private void Awake()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        text.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

And the procedure to add the score:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        ScoreManager.score = ScoreManager.score + score;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So what's the best way to do this without a static variable, and if someone could explain why using a static variable is not recommended will be more grateful.

### EDIT

Have tried the event handle way as @rogalski demonstrated in the answer, but the IDE shows that there is an error for type conversion on the lambda function of `ExecuteEvents.Execute<T>`
[image]

Comment: Using or not static variables is your own decision and depends on many circumstances. There is no general answer.

Comment: Indeed, this is an opinion based question which is off topic for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unity static variables in c# won't change by other script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553427/unity-static-variables-in-c-sharp-wont-change-by-other-script)

Comment: @NumLock It's the same code, same author but different kind of question. Read questions before flagging them.

Comment: @m.rogalski It's the same question and thus has been deleted. Have a nice day.

Comment: @NumLock OP Deleted it so your argument is invalid. These were two different questions and if you would care a bit you would've notice that. One was about why value was not incremented and this one is about why not to use static fields.

Comment: It is advised but not necessary in your current scenario it is valid but you are also free to adopt component based programming as unity also used this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remember that `Unity` is a [component based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering#Software_component) engine meaning that components have to do some specific work independently. This can be well combined with [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) methodology which mean that application ( or each of it's components ) are dependant on some event input.

`Unity` introduced really well designed [Event ( or Messaging )](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) system which you should use instead of making static fields, classes etc.

To point you out in the right way of implementing this I'll use the most trivial example.

*( EDIT -> Added definition for `EventData` which is required for `Unity`'s messaging system )*

First register your event :

```
public interface ICoinPickedHandler: IEventSystemHandler
{
    void OnCoinPickedUp(CoinPickedEventData eventData);
}
```

Then implement this EventTarget into your script :

```
public class ScoreManager
    : MonoBehaviour, ICoinPickedHandler
{
    private int m_Score;

    public void OnCoinPickedUp(CoinPickedEventData eventData)
    {
        this.m_Score += eventData.Score;
        eventData.Use();
    }

    // code to display score or whatever ...
}
```

Now to use this you have to just fire the event :

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        // assuming your collision.gameObject
        // has the ICoinPicker interface implemented
        ExecuteEvents.Execute<ICoinPickedHandler>(collision.gameObject, new CoinPickedEventData(score), (a,b)=>a.OnCoinPickedUp(b));
    }
}
```

Now you have to create [`EventData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.BaseEventData.html) :

```
public class CoinPickedEventData
    : BaseEventData
{
    public readonly int Score;

    public CoinPickedEventData(int score)
        : base(EventSystem.current)
    {
        Score = score;
    }
}
```

Of course this example requires from you to know the target to which you want to send that event. But if you do not know the target, you can use approach to `ExecuteHierarchy`.

More on that topic on [docs.unity3d.com](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.html).

Comment: thanks, @m.rogalski I will take time to digest the information you provide. that' very grateful

Comment: Proving the point about this is an opinion based question: I find the above excessively verbose/ a poor example of how the event system is supposed to be used. I.e. A score manager does not need explicit knowledge of coins - following that pattern, the score manager ends up with a potentially messy amount of interfaces for anything that can increase the score.

Comment: The way it's supposed to be used: A coin triggers a "score" event, and it subscribes to _that_.

Comment: One more thing to consider rogalsiki, should I put the interface in a single file like java or just put it together with the `ScoreManager` ? frankly, I'm not very familiar with C#, so need some fundamental guidance to write more maintainable code. Thanks again!

Comment: @LukeBriggs I don't get your point. What knowledge of coins? This is just a trivial example because it would take too much time to explain this in detail. Unity has about 10 pages about that topic just placing theoretical explanations. With code examples it would take another 10 pages extra. And yes, the coin is triggering an `ICoinPicker` event but "it subscribes to that" ? For me this statement makes no sense.

Comment: @armnotstrong This depends on you. I would prefer to make this in separate file ( `ICoinPicker.cs` and `ScoreManager.cs` ). But if you do not use this anywhere else than it make logical sense to put it in one file eg. `ScoreManager.cs`

Comment: @m.rogalski I'm using W3C terminology there - in short, the event flow is: [A coin collision] -> [A score event] -> [Received by the score listener]. Or e.g. [Mission completion] -> [A score event] -> [Received by the score listener]. A listener is said to be "subscribed" to an event. There's only one kind of score event, rather than `ScoreManager` having code for both coins and missions etc ("knowledge of coins" specifically meaning the `CoinPickedUp` method in `ScoreManager`).

Comment: @LukeBriggs In my example the `ScoreManager` is the listener and the part with `ExecuteEvents...` is the "Coin" element which is the sender. So basically It's the same as you've posted in the comment now :)

Comment: @m.rogalski It's _very_ different. Consider how you would add, for example, picking up diamonds. Or bonus points for completing something. In your example, each of these would have _their own distinct event_ - which would make `ScoreManager` get messy very quickly. I'll do a diagram if it helps.

Comment: @LukeBriggs How it would make `ScoreManager` messy? It has only one method ( `CoinPickedUp` ) which will be the same for every "diamond". At the end this one method will be called, keeping `ScoreManager` clean. It would depend on "diamond"/"coin" to distinguish to whom send this event execution. You can always use `EventTrigger` component to find out where to send this event.

Comment: So name the `pickup method` just `ScorePickup(int score)` will end this debate, right? :D

Comment: @armnotstrong Yep - call it something like `OnScore(int score)`, and e.g. `IScoreListener` rather than `ICoinPickup`. @m.rogalski because it makes no sense for a `CoinPickedUp` method to run when a diamond is picked up. Somebody new would most likely add `IDiamondPickup` and have ScoreManager handle them _both_ - that's how it starts getting very messy very quickly. If you're posting an answer relating to good design then good _naming_ is a high priority :)

Comment: ideally you would have a 3th class.. which catches the events and handles the score. manager and eventually other general stuff.. Something like a ScoreManagerBinder.  That way you can hook in diffirent score managers.. and the score manager itself doesnt need to worry about coins, diamonds , kills or whatever causes the score to change.

Comment: Hi, rogalski there seems a type convert error on the lambda function, could you check out the edit and point out what I have done wrong? :D

Comment: @armnotstrong You haven't done anything wrong. It is my mistake and I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Hi, rogalski, it still not working :-( , check the more edit

Comment: Forgot to pass `EventSystem` to the constructor ... :D

Comment: @MarkSmit That's not how events are supposed to work - you just have multiple listeners subscribed to the same event rather than any kind of event proxy :)

Comment: It all depends on your needs. In this particular situation @MarkSmit is right. There should be some `Binder` that will manage all of the bindings for that event.

Comment: @m.rogalski The general idea in Unity is you simply add multiple handlers to the same gameobject. GameObjects _are_ the binders; bubble the event if you need to. Anything more is unnecessary.

Comment: @LukeBriggs You must've misunderstood the concept of `GameObject`. It's not some kind of binder but simply it is a placeholder. Meaning it's just a "bucket" to which you dump all of your components. And no, the general idea in Unity is to simply operate on `Component`'s which should communicate with other `Component`s.

Comment: In the Unity event system, it acts like a 'bucket' to which you 'dump' all of your event targets - it _is_ a binder. Unity event targets _are_ components. I've worked with a little over 1000 Unity developers, so I'm pretty sure I understand how it's supposed to work :)

Comment: I've decided to write a blog with diagrams to try and make this point clearer - I appreciate that the event system (like many things in Unity) is broadly under documented so hopefully it will help clear some things up.

Comment: @m.rogalski Here's [a blog post with diagrams](http://futrworld.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/the-easy-reading-guide-to-unity-event.html) which should make the concept clearer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , it would be better to wrap the static variable in a method: addToScore , so in case behavior changes you only have to implement the changes once.

For the static variable: I think it would be better to make the score manager a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) instance instead of a static variable. Because then if you decide you need more score managers, reset the score manager, save more data in the score manager or whatever it will be a lot easier.